# Will an edit during the grace period update the original creation timestamp?

Tags: discussion, edits, grace-period, timestamps

Every now and then it happens that two users answer almost at the same time and the answer also is almost identical.

[This happened just to my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64658739/6413377).

When I was answering there of course was no identical answer. Soon after answering I added something to my post and saved the edits. After that edit I could see that there was [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64658736/6413377) identical to my own.

Checked the timestamps and noticed that this other answer was added 11 seconds before me. I cannot be sure what happened in the 30 second period I did this and that - maybe there was this banner telling me an answer was added but I did not notice it - but could it be that my edit reset the original answer timestamp?

Comment: So many "identical" answers in such a short time makes me wonder if maybe a dupe couldn't have been found to close that question. It's unusual for original questions that so many very similar answers are posted in a very short amount of time.

Comment: No, an edit shouldn't/doesn't the creation date. But adding a new post may not result in a full page reload, so it doesn't load answers which were posted while you were writing the answer.

Comment: Edits don't alter the time the post was created. The grace period would only hide if someone posted an answer, saw a newer answer, and then copied that newer answer into their own. I should also note that the answer code looks to be irreducible since you're just adding what appears to be basic syntax for the "helper" class. Without something clearly wrong, this isn't really mod flag material either.

Comment: The other answer has some typos: "Blue" needs to be lowercased, also "moutain" needs an "n".

Comment: Wow. That question is almost literal Bike-shedding.

Comment: No, time is not altered. I am often editing answers and every time after 5 min I see "edited" appears. To count that 5 min creation date should be preserved. Btw: you have the same link twice in your post, once you call it "my answer" and another time "another answer".

Comment: @Sinatr Thanks. Fixed. Btw; I guess the "answer id" in the url reveals also something. My: 64658739  vs. another: 64658736.

Answer (score 3):

No, every revision to a post, including its original version is saved in the [timeline for that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64658739/revisions). Also, re-editing a revision before the 5-minute mark preserves the original timeline; otherwise, you could continue editing the same revision indefinitely, as each saved edit would bump the timeline up a few minutes.

The behavior you're witnessing is an example of this general rule:

> As you interact with the site, the app refreshes the specific component you're interacting with.

I can't find a reference for this rule, but it manifests in numerous behaviors throughout the site, including voting and commenting.

Stack Overflow is a global application, and [Performance is a Feature](https://blog.codinghorror.com/performance-is-a-feature/). While you're composing an answer to a question, it's entirely possible that someone else has already posted theirs. StackOverflow doesn't refresh the page while you are composing your answer, nor after you have finished.

Here's a scenario that would plausibly lead to the results you experienced:

- You load the page, and begin composing an answer
- Another user does the same. This other user cannot see your answer, as you have not finished, yet.
- The other user posts a finished answer
- You post yours.
- You reload the page, and — surprise! — you've been scooped.